# Make my pseudocode real

Tags: code-golf, string

I've got some Java pseudocode that uses whitespace instead of curly braces, and I want *you* to convert it.

### I/O

Your program should take an input file along with a number designating how many spaces are used to indent a block. Here's an example:

```
$ convert.lang input.p 4
// Convert using 4 spaces as the block delimiter
$ convert.lang input.p 2
// Convert using 2 spaces as the block delimiter
```

It should then convert the result using the specified block delimiter and output the result to stdout.

### The meat of the program

Blocks open with `:` and each line within the block is indented using the block delimiter, like Python code.

```
while(true):
    System.out.println("Test");
```

Each `:` is replaced with a  `{`, and a `}` is appended to the end of the block.

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

### Examples

*Input:*

```
public class Test:
    public static void main(String[] args):
        System.out.println("Java is verbose...");
```

*Output:*

```
$ convert Test.pseudojava 4
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java is verbose...");
    }
}
```

*Input:*

```
main():
  printf("Hello World");
```

*Output:*

```
$ convert test.file 2
main() {
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

*Input:*

```
def generic_op(the_stack, func):
    # Generic op handling code
    b = the_stack.pop()
    if isinstance(b, list):
        if b:
            return
        top = b.pop(0)
        while b:
            top = func(top, b.pop(0))
        the_stack.push(top)
    else:
        a = the_stack.pop()
        return func(a, b)
```

*Output:*

```
$ convert code.py 4
def generic_op(the_stack, func){
    # Generic op handling code
    b = the_stack.pop()
    if isinstance(b, list) {
        if b {
            return
        }
        top = b.pop(0)
        while b {
            top = func(top, b.pop(0))
        }
        the_stack.push(top)
    }
    else {
        a = the_stack.pop()
        return func(a, b)
    }
}
```

### Scoring

The code with the least amount of [bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins!

Comment: Can we assume that the input contains no comments?

Comment: @MartinBüttner It may contain comments, but the comments won't contain ':'. Basically, yes.

Comment: What about labels, which are the usual reason that a line would end in a colon in valid Java source?

Comment: I've never seen a label anywhere but the beginning of a line.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Just ignore those. Let's assume the programmer who made it knew not to use them.

Comment: I've just been reminded of how much I hate Java.

Comment: Is the indentation block size a required parameter?

Comment: @NotthatCharles not if you can detect it automatically, but otherwise yes

Comment: Why would anyone want to convert OUT of <s>Python</s> pseudocode.

Comment: `System.out.println("Java is verbose...");` ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 41 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p0
1while s/( *).*\K:((
\1 .*)+)/ {\2
\1}/
```

Counting the shebang as two, input is taken from stdin. A command line argument need not be provided. Any valid nesting context can be determined (and matched) without knowing the indentation size.

---

**Regex Break-Down**

```perl
( *)                   # as many spaces as possible (\1)
    .*                 # as many non-newline characters as possible \
                         (greediness ensures this will always match a full line)
      \K               # keep all that (i.e. look-behind assertion)
        :              # colon at eol (newline must be matched next)
         (
          (
           \n\1        # newline with at least one more space than the first match
                .*     # non-newlines until eol
                  )+   # as many of these lines as possible
                    )  # grouping (\2)
```

---

**Sample Usage**

*in1.dat*

```perl
public class Test:
    public static void main(String[] args):
        System.out.println("Java is verbose...");
```

*Output*

```perl
$ perl py2java.pl < in1.dat
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java is verbose...");
    }
}
```

---

*in2.dat*

```perl
main():
  printf("Hello World");
```

*Output*

```perl
$ perl py2java.pl < in2.dat
main() {
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

---

*in3.dat*

```perl
def generic_op(the_stack, func):
    # Generic op handling code
    b = the_stack.pop()
    if isinstance(b, list):
        if b:
            return
        top = b.pop(0)
        while b:
            top = func(top, b.pop(0))
        the_stack.push(top)
    else:
        a = the_stack.pop()
        return func(a, b)
```

*Output*

```perl
$ perl py2java.pl < in3.dat
def generic_op(the_stack, func) {
    # Generic op handling code
    b = the_stack.pop()
    if isinstance(b, list) {
        if b {
            return
        }
        top = b.pop(0)
        while b {
            top = func(top, b.pop(0))
        }
        the_stack.push(top)
    }
    else {
        a = the_stack.pop()
        return func(a, b)
    }
}
```

Comment: i just wrote this in ruby

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>299</s> 265 bytes

```
import sys;s=int(sys.argv[2]);t="";b=0
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
 h=l;g=0
 for c in l:
  if c!=" ":break
  g+=1
 if g/s<b:h=" "*g+"}\n"+h;b-=1
 if l.strip().endswith(":"):h=l.split(":")[0];h+=" {";b+=1
 t+=h+"\n"
b-=1
while b>-1:
 t+=" "*(b*s)+"}\n"b-=1
print(t)
```

Boom bam pow.

Algorithm used:

```
//global vars
string total //total modified program
int b //indent buffer

line thru lines: //iterate over every line
  string mline = "" //line to be added to the total

  //calculate the amount of spaces before the line (could be a lot easier)
  int spaces = 0 //total spaces
  c thru line: //go through every character in the line
    if c != " ": //if the current char isn't a space (meaning we went though all of them
        break //break out of iterating through chars
    spaces++ //increment the spaces because we've hit a space (hurr derr)

  if spaces/SPACE_SETTING < b: //if indent count of the current line is less than the indent buffer
    mline = "}\n" + line //add closing bracket to beginning of line
    b-- //decrement buffer

  if line.endswith(":"): //if the line ends with a `:`
    remove : from line
    mline += " {" //append {
    b++ //increment buffer
  total += mline //add modified line to total

print(total)
```

Comment: Can you include an explanation?

Comment: @TanMath Added the algorithm I used

Comment: Does it work with Python 2?

Comment: @wb9688 No idea, I only tested it with Python 3

Comment: I just tested, and it works with Python 2

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 70

```
x=$_+"
"
1while x.sub! /^(( *).*):
((\2 .*?
)*)/,'\1 {
\3\2}
'
$><<x
```

Adds a trailing newline.  Does not need the indent block-size parameter.

Run this with `-n0` (this is really 68+2).  Thank you greatly to @primo for saving over a dozen bytes.

Comment: I think `-p0` also works for ruby (`-0` reads all input at once, `-p` stores stdin into `$_`, and auto-prints it at the end).

Comment: @primo Good point.  In case it wasn't clear with my comment above, this isn't a port of your code, but my own work that does exactly what yours does (but with more bytes)

Comment: I understood correctly, just providing a tip to remove the (rather verbose) `x=$<.readlines*''`. While I'm doing that, `sub!` also has a two parameter overload (rather than one paramater + block) that accepts a replacement string, so you can use `\1`, `\2`, etc. instead of needing to concatenate it all.

Comment: @primo Thanks!  I tried the two-parameter version before and abandoned it at some point last night.