# Output the qwerty keyboard

Tags: code-golf, keyboard

Given a character, output (to the screen) the entire qwerty keyboard layout (with spaces and newlines) that follows the character. The examples make it clear.

Input 1

```
f
```

Output 1

```
g h j k l
z x c v b n m
```

Input 2

```
q
```

Output 2

```
w e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m
```

Input 3

```
m
```

Output 3

(Program terminates without output)

Input 4

```
l
```

Output 4

```
z x c v b n m
```

**Shortest code wins.** (in bytes)

P.S.

Extra newlines, or extra spaces at the end of a line are accepted.

Comment: Is a function sufficient or do you require a full program that reads/writes to stdin/stdout?

Comment: @agtoever As per http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/is-a-function-allowed, it is allowed. However, the function must still output to the screen .

Comment: @agtoever Try this link instead. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet

Comment: I like the ones that don't have the keyboard layout visible explicitly in the code.  They should get bonus marks :)

Comment: At first i was confused by input 4, then I realised that it's a small L and not a decimal one

Comment: are leading space before a line allowed?

Comment: @SahilArora Nope.

Comment: Might this qualify for [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] ? Not sure though

Answer (score 20):

### CJam, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
"wertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm"q/W=S%Sf*N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22wertyuiop%20asdfghjkl%20zxcvbnm%22q%2FW%3DS%25Sf*N*&input=f)

#### Explanation

```
"we...nm"
     e# Push the letters in order, without q. We don't need q, because it will never
     e# be part of the output.
q/   e# Split the string around the input. If the input is "q", the entire string
     e# will go into a single chunk.
W=   e# Select the last chunk.
S%   e# Split the string around spaces, discarding empty segments (only relevant for the 
     e# first segment if the input is "p" or "l").
Sf*  e# Join each line by spaces.
N*   e# Join the lines by linefeeds.
```

Comment: What is `e#`? Is it the CJam syntax for a comment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @A.L yes it is.

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth, 33 bytes

```
jjL\ cec."`zÈ´ýß44,ûtKÕÀ@"z\`
```

Note that some characters are unprintable. Try it online in the [Pyth Compiler](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjL%5C+cec.%22%60z%01%1E%C3%88%10%C2%B4%C3%BD%C3%9F44%2C%C3%BBtK%C3%95%C3%80%04%40%22z%5C%60&input=f&debug=0).

#### How it works

```
jjL\ cec."`z…"z\`

        ."`z…"     Unpack …, with lowest character '`' and highest character `z`.
       c      z    Split at occurrences of the input (z).
      e            Retrieve the last resulting chunk.
     c         \`  Split into rows, at backticks.
 jL\               Separate the characters of each row by spaces.
j                  Separate the rows by linefeeds.
```

Comment: Aw man, I had just created my first Pyth program ever (only 38 bytes!), then you came along... +1 BTW, I think `\ ` is equivalent to `d`.

Comment: Oops, I guess it's not the same... what's different?

Comment: @ETHproductions @Dennis Same reason why `md5` doesn't produce 5 spaces. `d` is the default variable that iterates through the iterable argument of the map operator. And `jL\ <list>` is simply a shortcut for the map operator `mj\ d<list>`.

Comment: @Jakube Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

## Perl, 56 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
'qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm'=~/$_
?/;$_=$';s/\B/ /g
```

Counting the shebang as 3, input is taken from stdin. If a leading newline isn't a concern for inputs `p` and `l`, then `/$_\n?/` could be replaced with a bare `$_` to save 4.

---

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo g|perl qwerty.pl
h j k l
z x c v b n m

$ echo v|perl qwerty.pl
b n m
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching [me about `\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes)!

Comment: @DomHastings in this case, it wasn't really necessary for the byte count, `s/.\B/$& /g` would work equally well. A [better example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64020).

Answer (score 6):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
♦wertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm♣B3$,■♪2◙
```

The source code uses the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) encoding. [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=4pmmd2VydHl1aW9wIGFzZGZnaGprbCB6eGN2Ym5t4pmjQjMkLOKWoOKZqjLil5k&input=Zg)

#### Test run

```
$ base64 -d > qwerty.gs2 <<< BHdlcnR5dWlvcCBhc2RmZ2hqa2wgenhjdmJubQVCMyQs/g0yCg==
$ wc -c qwerty.gs2
37 qwerty.gs2
$ echo -n f | gs2 qwerty.gs2
g h j k l
z x c v b n m
```

#### How it works

```
♦                                      Begin string literal.
 wertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm
                            ♣          End string literal.
                             B         Swap the string with the input.
                              3        Split the string at the input character.
                               $       Select the last chunk.
                                ,      Split the selected chunk at spaces.
                                 ■     Map over the resulting array:
                                  ♪      Push ' '.
                                   2     Join the characters, separating by ' '.
                                    ◙    Push a linefeed.
```

Answer (score 6):

## C#, 112 bytes <s>105</s> <s>110</s>

Count went up by 5 bytes, but more correct! Thanks @MartinBüttner!!

```
void c(char i){System.Console.Write(@"q w e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m".Split(i)[1].Trim());}
```

Un-golfed

```
void c(char i)
{
    System.Console.Write(@"q w e r t y u i o p
    a s d f g h j k l
    z x c v b n m".Split(i)[1].Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```
x=>[...`qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm`].join` `.split(x)[1]
```

Uses the same technique as most other answers. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you explain why do you use the "...". I try without on JSFiddle and still working?

Comment: @Awashi It is a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). It separates the string into an array of characters. Without it the `.join\` \`` would do nothing and there would be no spaces in the result.

Comment: @user81655 Tank you

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 83 bytes

```py
lambda c,s="q w e r t y u i o p\na s d f g h j k l\nz x c v b n m":s[s.index(c)+2:]
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/mYlGTU)

Answer (score 4):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), <s>50</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

TeaScript is JavaScript for golfing.

```
`qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm`.s×[1]s(b)j(p)
```

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
`qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm`.s(x)[1]s(b)j(p)

      // Implicit: x = input string
`...` // Take the qwerty string,
.s(x) // and split it at the input.
[1]   // Take the second item from this,
s(b)  // split it into chars,
j(p)  // and join the result with spaces.
      // Implicit: output final expression
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>63</s> 57 bytes

Takes the character as command line argument: `ruby keyboard.rb e`

```rb
"qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm".scan$*[0]
puts$'.chars*' '
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 73

```
f=x=>[...(k=`qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm`).slice(k.search(x)+1)].join` `
```

If a leading newline is not allowed when parameter is `p` or `l`, then **83**

```
f=x=>(k=`q w e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m`).slice(k.search(x)+2)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Sed, 59 characters

(58 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```
s/./&qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm/
s/(.).*\1//
s/\w/& /g
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n 'f' | sed -r 's/./&qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm/;s/(.).*\1//;s/\w/& /g'
g h j k l 
z x c v b n m
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>86</s> <s>87</s> <s>83</s> <s>71</s> 66

```
puts"qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm ".split($*[0])[1].gsub /./,'\& '
```

The extra space after `m` is to prevent the program from crashing if the input is 'm'.

Thanks to @manatwork for ~16 bytes of tips

Comment: Let me guess… Too many Python coding in the last time?

Comment: Some minor syntax changes: `ARGV` → `$*`; `each_char` → `chars`; `do`..`end` → `{`..`}`; `printf` → `$><<` + `%` would lead to this: `"qwertyuiop↵asdfghjkl↵zxcvbnm".split($*[0])[1].chars{|i|$><<"%s "%i}`. More in [Tips for golfing in Ruby](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby).

Comment: @manatwork First time trying to golf in Ruby, thanks for the tips/link!

Comment: I see you didn't got the hint in my first comment. In Ruby there is no need for triple quotes around multiline strings. (Actually I had no idea until now that it accepted by Ruby.)

Comment: @manatwork Whoops. Didn't know that either; thought you meant something else.

Comment: The leading spaces in the output are quite ugly. As `.` in regular expression does not match `\n` by default, better use that for the spacing: `puts"qwertyuiop↵asdfghjkl↵zxcvbnm ".split($*[0])[1].gsub(/./,'\& ')`. Though the code length will remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 88 bytes

```php
<?=$m[1&ereg("$argn.(.*)",'q w e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m',$m)];
```

Requires the `-F` command line option, counted as 3. Default .ini setting are assumed (you may disable your local .ini with `-n`).

---

**Sample Usage**

```php
$ echo g|php -F qwerty.php
h j k l
z x c v b n m

$ echo v|php -F qwerty.php
b n m
```

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog (SWI), <s>153</s> 133 bytes

**Edit:** Cut 20 bytes with tips from @Fatalize

**Code**

```
b([A,_|T],[H]):-A=H,writef('%s',[T]);b(T,[H]).
p(X):-name(X,C),b(`q w e r t y u i o p \r\na s d f g h j k l \r\nz x c v b n m`,C),!.
```

**Explanation**

```
p(X):-name(X,C),                                                               % Get charcode of input
      b(`q w e r t y u i o p \r\na s d f g h j k l \r\nz x c v b n m`,C),!.    % Get keyboard chars as charcodes and call b
b([A,_|T],[H]):-A=H,                                                           % If list head is input element
                writef('%s',[T]);                                              % Interpret list as charcodes and print as string
                b(T,[H]).                                                      % Else remove first element of list and try again
```

**Examples**

```
>p(f).
g h j k l 
z x c v b n m

>p(q).
w e r t y u i o p 
a s d f g h j k l 
z x c v b n m
```

Comment: Using SWI-Prolog, you could shorten the `atom_codes` part by using the backquotes which delimit string codes (so you could replace directly L in the call of `b` with the string).

Comment: @Fatalize cool! As I'm using SWI-Prolog for testing anyway, that sounds like a great idea.

Comment: Also, using `b([A,_|T],[H]):-A=H,writef('%s',[T]);b(T,[H]).` instead of 2 different rules for `b` is 7 bytes shorter. Usually, it's always shorter to merge all rules into a single one with ORs `;` instead of writing multiple rules, because you avoid repeating the predicate's name and parameters and you avoid a linefeed too ;)

Comment: It's been so long since I learned Prolog that I had totally forgotten that you could OR like that. Great tip! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>49</s> <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 38 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
`qØÆyuiop\n?dfghjkl\nzxcvbnm`qU g1 ¬qS
```

The `?` should be the unprintable Unicode char U+0086.

#### How it works

```
          // Implicit: U = input char
`...`     // Take the compressed string and decompress it.
qU g1     // Split the string at the input and take the second item.
¬qS       // Split into chars, then join with spaces.
          // Implicit: output final expression
```

Now beating CJam! :) Suggestions welcome!

#### Non-competing version, 12 bytes

```
;Dv qU g1 ¬¸
```

As of Jan 11, I've [added](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt/commit/0e43c90f2853308f4f7f7aca7759dd29a1eac1a5) a cool new feature to Japt: If the program contains a leading comma, the variables `ABCDEFGHIJL` are redefined to various values. `D` is set to `"QWERTYUIOP\nASDFGHJKL\nZXCVBNM"`, so `;Dv` is enough to replace the string here.

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, 122 bytes

```
"m n b v c x z"25*"l k j h g f d s a"v
v1-")"g2-"U"~"q w e r t y u i o p"*25<
>-:#v_$>:#,_@ZVD0FHJ:LNP^\<>,2B48X.T6R
^1$\<
```

It has been tested here: [Befunge-93 Interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html).

#### How it works

- `'q w e r t y u i o p\na s d f g h j k l\nz x c v b n m'` is pushed on the stack.
- The number of values to discard (hardcoded in `@ZVD0FHJ:LNP^\<>,2B48X.T6R`) N is pushed.
- First N values are discarded and the remaining values are printed.

#### Note

I picked the encoding so the string starts with `@` in order to overlap with the program. This string is generated with the following python code:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
base = 'q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n m'
print(''.join(chr(base.index(x) + 32 + 9 + 3) for x in letters))
```

Comment: Good first answer! Welcome to Code Golf SE. (I'm new as well.)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <s>58</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes ##

```
lambda x:" ".join("qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm".split(x)[1])
```

Takes input as a string or char.
Splits the string at the input and prints off everything after the split.

(First time code-golfing, please be gentle :P )

EDIT: Didn't see the additional spaces required between characters, added now

EDIT 2: Modified to be an anonymous lambda function and removing the additional split arg, saving 4 bytes

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I don't think you need the space after `print`, but it seems that this doesn't print the spaces between each pair of letters.

Comment: Can't provide a reference right now, but when the interpreter requires extra formatting of the input, that is also included in the count. (Correct me if I am wrong, but I think this only works if the input is passed together with surrounded quotes, like `"f"`.)

Comment: Nice first golf. Functions are allowed by default, even anonymous ones, so it's shorter to do this as `lambda s:...`. I think the split doesn't need an arg of `1`, since the character appears only once. This outputs spaces at the start of succeeding lines, not sure if that's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## Mumps - 102 Bytes

Golfed script:

```
S A="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",B=0 R P F I=1:1:$L(A) S Q=$E(A,I) W:B Q," " X:"qpl"[Q "W !" S:Q=P B=1
```

Ungolfed and commented:

```
 S A="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" ; Need the qwerty order
 S B=0 ; boolean flag for printing, default to false.
 R P   ; read from stdin into P
 F I=1:1:$L(A) D   ; Count I from 1 to length of qwerty variable; do all of the following:
 . S Q=$E(A,I)     ; Extract 1 letter (at position I) from A and save in Q.
 . W:B Q," "       ; If our print flag (B) is true, print the letter in Q & a space.
 . X:"qpl"[Q "W !" ; If Q is q, p or l, write a cr/lf
 . S:Q=P B=1       ; If Q == P (stdin) change our print flag from false to true.
```

The rule allowing extra newlines saved me almost 10 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 88 bytes

```
function s(d){alert("qw e r t y u i o p\na s d f g h j k l\nz x c v b n m".split(d)[1])}
```

(no need in the space after the first char, as it never gets to the output)

Alerts the keyboard when you call `s("some letter")`. Can be also made with `document.write()` or `console.log()`, but hey, it's longer :P

Demo:

```js
function s(d){alert("qw e r t y u i o p\na s d f g h j k l\nz x c v b n m".split(d)[1])}

s(prompt("Enter the key"));
```

Comment: You could probably save a few bytes by just using `\n` instead of `;` in the string and getting rid of the replace.

Comment: @Eth Sure, thanks! I did use the replace, because at first, without counting the line breaks, the replace would shorten. Then I've noticed that the line breaks should be there, so I've used replace again. Didn't even think it could make the code longer :D

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 107 bytes

```
void q(char c){System.out.print("qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm ".split(""+c)[1].replaceAll("\\w","$0 "));}
```

Ungolfed with wrapper-class reading from System.in

```
public class Qwerty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Qwerty().q(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next().charAt(0));
    }
    void q(char c) {
        System.out.print("qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm ".split(""+c)[1].replaceAll("\\w","$0 "));
    }
}
```

If spaces at *start-of-line* were acceptable, we could go down to 99 bytes:

```
void q(char c){System.out.print("qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm ".split(""+c)[1].replace(""," "));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <del>59 57</del>  67 bytes

Added spaces between letters

```
puts"qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm".split(gets.chop)[-1].chars*' '
```

Comment: This fails on input “m”. That can be easily fixed by changing the array index from -1 to 1, but then on input “m” will result `nil`. Which is not a problem itself, but will cause you problems when finishing your code to add spaces between the letters.

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 machine code + DOS, 61 bytes

Hexdump (with ASCII view on the right):

```
B8 1E 01 8B F8 CD 21 B1 1F F2 AE 8B F7 AC 8A D0 ......!.........
B4 02 CD 21 80 E2 20 74 02 CD 21 E2 F0 C3 71 77 ...!.. t..!...qw
65 72 74 79 75 69 6F 70 0D 0A 61 73 64 66 67 68 ertyuiop..asdfgh
6A 6B 6C 0D 0A 7A 78 63 76 62 6E 6D 0D          jkl..zxcvbnm.
```

Assembly source code (can be assembled with tasm):

```
    .MODEL TINY

    .CODE
    org 100h

    MAIN PROC

    mov ax, offset qwerty ; sets ah=1 (coincidence)
    mov di, ax      ; di points to the string
    int 21h         ; reads a char from keyboard into al

    mov cl, 31      ; cx is the length of the string
    repne scasb     ; look for the char
    mov si, di      ; si now points beyond the found char

myloop:
    lodsb           ; load a char
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h         ; output the char

    and dl, 20h     ; if it's a letter, set it to a space
    jz print_done   ; if it's not a letter, don't print a space
    int 21h         ; if it's a letter, print a space
print_done:
    loop myloop     ; repeat until end of string

    ret

qwerty db 'qwertyuiop',13,10,'asdfghjkl',13,10,'zxcvbnm',13

    MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

Two fun things here:

1. The offset of the `qwerty` string is `0x011e`. The upper byte of it is 1, which is the DOS function number for character input. This saves 1 byte in the code.
2. All lower-case letters have bit 5 set. When doing an `AND` with `0x20`, they are all turned into a space, which is then printed. If the previous char was an end-of-line byte, it gets turned into 0, and no space is output. This is used to avoid the nonsensical sequence `0d 20 0a 20` at end of line.

One almost-fun thing:

I tried to search for the input char starting at address 0 (that decreased program size by 2 bytes), instead of the usual place (start of the string). This almost worked; however, it failed for input `t`, because the code itself contains the byte `t` (as part of the encoding of a conditional jump). So for `t`, it would output a few junk bytes:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

## O 2.2, <s>48</s> 46 characters

```
"qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm
"i/r;s{n.U=ST?}d
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ./o keyboard.o <<< 'f'
g h j k l 
z x c v b n m
```

### O, 61 characters

```
"qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm\n"i/r;""/rl{.o"\n"={}{' o}?}d
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ java xyz.jadonfowler.o.O keyboard.o <<< 'f'
g h j k l 
z x c v b n m
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the IDE for some reason, looking into it now...

Comment: `"qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm\n"i/r;s{n.'\n=ST?}d` only works on the new interpreter but is 51 bytes.

Comment: The permalinks are... a work in progress :P

Comment: Yup, in the libregexp directory

Comment: git clone the repo, then `git submodule update --init`, then `make`

Comment: Thank you, @phase. Even better, as the C interpreter supports embedded newlines, so no more literal `\n`. ☺

Answer (score 1):

**SQL (MS T-SQL), 172 bytes**

```
CREATE PROC c @I CHAR(1) AS DECLARE @S CHAR(49) SET @S = 'w e r t y u i o p' + CHAR(13) + 'a s d f g h j k l' + CHAR(13) + 'z x c v b n m' PRINT RIGHT(@S,LEN(@S)-CHARINDEX(@I,@S))
```

Ungolfed:

```
CREATE PROC c                           -- Create a procedure named "c"
    @I CHAR(1)                          -- Which is invoked with a single character input (@I)
AS

DECLARE @S CHAR(49) = 'w e r t y u i o p' + CHAR(13) + 'a s d f g h j k l' + CHAR(13) + 'z x c v b n m' -- Initialise the entire output omitting "q " as @S
PRINT RIGHT(@S,LEN(@S)-CHARINDEX(@I,@S))    -- Use the charindex funtion to effectively substring @S
```

I'm new here, only just discovered this site.  No idea if I've posted correctly or if T-SQL is allowed but I know the procedure above works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 114 Bytes

```
func main(){k="qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm\n"foreach(l in k.substring(k.index(input())))print(l!="\n"?l+" ":l)}
```

Run online and see expanded with test case [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=f0fbf3d3e9709da3dfaa3c9942e80b22)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-hR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;Dv qU ®·®¬¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWhS&code=O0R2IHFVIK63rqy4&input=InEi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 38 bytes

```
↓2↓≠←⁰¶mJ' ¶¨qw²yuiop₄sdfghjkl¶zxcvbnm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbZCMgftS54FHbhEeNGw5ty/VSVzi07dCKwvJDmypLM/MLHjW1FKekpWdkZecc2lZVkVyWlJf7////dAA)

Comment: I wrote a smug comment thinking that I'd beaten you by 10 bytes, before realising that I hadn't read the question properly...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen No worries, happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>29</s> 35 bytes

*Edit +6 bytes when I realised that the letters need to be separated by spaces*

```
¶mJ' ¶!2x¨qw²yuiop₄sdfghjkl¶zxcvbnm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@hbble6gqHtikaVRxaUVh@aFNlaWZ@waOmluKUtPSMrOycQ9uqKpLLkvJy////H62epq6jXgjEuUCcox4LAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 53 bytes

```
{` 0:1_*|x\"\n"/" "/'$$`qwertyuiop`asdfghjkl`zxcvbnm}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqjpBwcDKMF6rpiJGKSZPSV9JQUlfXUUlobA8taiksjQzvyAhsTglLT0jKzsnoaoiuSwpL7f2f5qCUqHSfwA)

Uses `` "\n"/" "/'$$`...`...`... `` to (slightly) compress `"q w e r t y u i o p\na s d f g h j k l\nz x c v b n m"`.

It then splits that string on the input character, taking the remainder that occurs after that character.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 77 bytes

```javascript
alert(`w e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m`.split(prompt())[1])
```

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bvf3jrm/)

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 56 characters

```
?=@subst{\\A\*?=\;\?=\? ;qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n 'f' | gema '?=@subst{\\A\*?=\;\?=\? ;qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm}'
g h j k l 
z x c v b n m
```

Answer (score 0):

## , 32 chars / 79 bytes

```
⟦ɘƄ瀛ذ鸊ް΀ꀆဓƘ᳀ᘁ堍怍訁码聮Ęݠⶰ䀀#]ø⬭Čï⎖1
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=q&code=%E2%9F%A6%C9%98%C6%84%E7%80%9B%D8%B0%E9%B8%8A%EE%82%96%DE%B0%CE%80%EA%80%86%E1%80%93%C6%98%E1%B3%80%E1%98%81%E5%A0%8D%E6%80%8D%E8%A8%81%E7%A0%81%EE%80%B1%E8%81%AE%C4%98%DD%A0%E2%B6%B0%E4%80%80%23%5D%C3%B8%E2%AC%AD%C4%8C%C3%AF%E2%8E%961)</kbd>

At least I'm winning in char count... (Byte count's a different story.)

Oh yeah, just realized that I implemented index shortcuts (`⎖1` instead of `[1]`) awhile back. Silly me!

Comment: What language is this? or is it literally this: http://i.imgur.com/WC7XvYs.png (and is there documentation) it's weird, aha!

Comment: This is ESMin. Letters are in doublestruck, so you might have trouble seeing them. See github.com/molarmanful/ESMin (docs are outdated, though).

Answer (score 0):

## C++, <s>129, 112</s> 97 bytes

```
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>
void o(char c){puts(strstr("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",&c));}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>
void o(char c)
{
    puts(strstr("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",&c));
}
```

Comment: You could shave off 17 bytes by using `puts` instead of `std::cout<<`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks! An excellent point: for some reason I thought I would still need an `#include` for `puts`, but evidently I do not!

Comment: Also, [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%23include%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Avoid%20o%28char%20c%29%7Bputs%28strstr%28%22qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm%22%2C%20%26c%29%29%3B%7D) is another 12 shorter.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know `strstr` was a thing.

Comment: I think that's a little bit overgolfed. You need `<stdio.h>` for `strstr`.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Hmm I managed to compile it just fine in VS2013 by simply `#include<string`, but [you're right](https://ideone.com/Ev5q5q). I will update the answer. Thanks for sticking it through with me!

Comment: Aren't there missing some newlines and spaces from the output?

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 206 + 2 = 208 bytes

Because this uses delayed expansion you need to invoke it with `CMD /V /C keyboard.cmd <letter>`, so adding <s>1</s>2 for the `/V` switch.

```
@echo off
set a=q w e r t y u i o p
set b=a s d f g h j k l
set c=z x c v b n m
if not "!a:*%1 =!"=="!a!" echo !a:*%1 =!
if not "!a:*%1=!!b:*%1 =!"=="!a!!b!" echo !b:*%1 =!
if not %1==m echo !c:*%1 =!
```

Comment: I'm afraid the command line option would count 1 if `cmd` would accept it as `/VC`, like POSIX tools do. But as I know `/V` requires its own `/`, which also gets counted.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 109 bytes

I know its a bit large but its all I know how to do right now!

```
def kb(c): 
 s = "q w e r t y u i o p \n a s d f g h j k l \n z x c v b n m"
 a = s.split(c)
 print(a[1])
```

Comment: I don't think you need the call to `kb()` at the end; defining the function is enough. Also, 1 space of indentation is enough. After making these changes, I get 108 bytes, using [this site](http://bytesizematters.com).

Comment: @ETHproductions wow I didn't know that once space thing. (New to python). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 83 bytes

```
<?=trim(explode($argv[1],"qw e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m")[1]);
```

Takes the letter from the command line, like:

```
$ qwerty.php y
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 80 bytes

```
x="qwertzuiop\nasdfghjkl\nyxcvbnm"&&echo -e ${x#*$1}|sed 's/./& /g'
```

Try it yourself, either replace *$1* with desired character or make a #!/bin/bash script.

Here are some samples from cygwin:

```
$x="qwertzuiop\nasdfghjkl\nyxcvbnm"&&echo -e ${x#*q}|sed 's/./& /g'
w e r t z u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
y x c v b n m

$x="qwertzuiop\nasdfghjkl\nyxcvbnm"&&echo -e ${x#*m}|sed 's/./& /g'

$x="qwertzuiop\nasdfghjkl\nyxcvbnm"&&echo -e ${x#*h}|sed 's/./& /g'
j k l
y x c v b n m
```

It's not the shortest, but I'm still proud of it!

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 74 bytes

Took a different approach than [@Cajova_Houba's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65187/39056), so I posted it separately. Ended up not being too much shorter because I initially forgot to deal with space-separating the output.

```
cut -d"$1" -f2<<<"qwertzuiop asdfghjkl yxcvbnm"|tr ' ' "\n"|sed 's/./& /g'
```

Takes input as a command line argument, or just replace `$1` manually and run it straight from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 79 bytes

```hs
drop 2.snd.(`span`"q w e r t y u i o p\na s d f g h j k l\nz x c v b n m").(/=)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcYxDoIwGIDRq3zpBIlg4l5PoJOjJVrBilp@CkVFD29NfNNrbbyfvU9Om9SMfWBVRmnK7BiDlaMaeHFmZOLNgys9wYgl0uC40HLjjjfyYabmyQmhU3mZLXWeOnsVNJ0NWzIzU6z/PxAe024aN8J@P1cLpbVWC8f8nxEjqspRbui8St/aeXuJqahD@AE)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 57 bytes

```c
f(c){puts(strchr("qwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl\nzxcvbnm",c)+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFLDoIwEADQfU/R4IKZ@ElcYzwJG5xSOgoD9AMq4ezV9@jcEeUDC/XJtPoWouHx4u7ZAuE2pRggRE/OQzGvrY@fxONUSxOM7dzz1dfyfdPykKE4ER6vWO2ZJeqhYQHUm1L6z0I5l1ipPf8A)